# get average from while loop in C using the same variable

Tags: c, while-loop, average

I have a variable `total` that stores the total of miles and gallons every time user enters it.

When user hits -1, the program is suppose to add all the totals together and take the average. 
I can't get the variable to add the previous total value to itself for the next iteration of the loop.

I tried `totals += totals;` but that returns the last total value of the loop?

what am i doing wrong?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

const float EXIT_VALUE = -1.0f;

int main(void)
{
    float gallons; // number of gallons used
    float miles; // number of miles driven
    float totals; // total = miles * gallons
    int numOfEntries = 0; // number of entries 
    float avgConsumption = 0; // avg of all entries made by user

    // get number of gallons from user
    printf("%s%.1f%s", "Enter the gallons used (", EXIT_VALUE, " to end): ");
    scanf("%f", &gallons);

    // loops until user enter -1 
    while (gallons != EXIT_VALUE) {
        //miles driven by user
        printf("%s", "Enter the miles driven: "); 
        scanf("%f", &miles);

        // calculate total miles per gallon
        totals = miles/gallons;
        printf("The miles/gallons for this tank was %.6f\n\n", totals);

        // get number of gallons from user
        printf("%s%.2f%s", "Enter the gallons used (", EXIT_VALUE, " to end): ");
        scanf("%f", &gallons);

        totals += totals;
        numOfEntries++;
        avgConsumption = totals / numOfEntries;

    } // end while
    printf("\nThe overall average miles/gallon was %.6f: ", avgConsumption);

    _getch();
    return 0;

} // end main
```

Comment: `totals += totals` is the same as multiplying `totals` by 2. I am pretty sure average is calculated differently

Comment: what I meant to say was, the average here is calculated at "avgConsumption = totals / numOfEntries", where totals is the total number of totals from all iterations of the loop and numOfEntries is the number of times the user was asked to enter the totals

Comment: And as I said, `totals` are not calculated properly

Comment: Print miles per gallons for each tank, without storing into totals. Add up all the miles in totals. At the end divide totals by number of tanks times gallons  per tank. Or add up totals+=miles/gallonsInTank and divide by number of tank at the end..

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is have a variable that adds up all of the totals, and then when the loop is complete, divides the number by your avgConsumption variable.

Here is a slight modification of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const float EXIT_VALUE = -1.0f;

int main(void)
{
    float gallons; // number of gallons used
    float miles; // number of miles driven
    float totals = 0; // total = miles * gallons
    int numOfEntries = 0; // number of entries
    float avgConsumption = 0; // avg of all entries made by user

    // get number of gallons from user
    printf("%s%.1f%s", "Enter the gallons used (", EXIT_VALUE, " to end): ");
    scanf("%f", &gallons);

    // loops until user enter -1
    while (gallons != EXIT_VALUE) {
        //miles driven by user
        printf("%s", "Enter the miles driven: ");
        scanf("%f", &miles);

        // calculate total miles per gallon
        float curTotal = miles/gallons;
        printf("The miles/gallons for this tank was %.6f\n\n", curTotal);

        // get number of gallons from user
        printf("%s%.2f%s", "Enter the gallons used (", EXIT_VALUE, " to end): ");
        scanf("%f", &gallons);

        totals += curTotal;
        numOfEntries++;

    } // end while
    avgConsumption = totals / numOfEntries;
    printf("\nThe overall average miles/gallon was %.6f: ", avgConsumption);


    return 0;

} // end main
```

What I did was use totals to add up all of the miles/gallons you received in your loop. I used a local variable curTotal to store the actual miles/gallons calculation. This variable is reset for every iteration of the loop. After th loop concludes, I calculated avgConsumption, instead of calculating it in the loop which produces different results. This gives you the average number of miles per gallon reported by users.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you are getting the right "total" at all

It is getting over-written every time you reiterate through the while-loop.

Make another variable to hold the "total" and one variable that you can store "miles/gallons" by -- like 'MPG'

Then at the end you can do Total = Total + MPG.

Answer (score 0):

> what am i doing wrong?

Code is mis-calculating totals.

To average multiple quotients like many miles_per_gallon (MPG), usually the approach is to divide the total_miles/total_gallons.  This is not the *only* definition of the *average MPG* yet I am certain the best to use here.  [@Yunnosch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376170/get-average-from-while-loop-in-c-using-the-same-variable/44378201#comment75753582_44376170)

```
// Pseudo code
total_miles = 0.0
total_gallons = 0.0
while (still_getting_input)
  miles = get_input();
  gallons = get_input();
  print miles, gallons, miles/gallon

  total_miles += miles
  total_gallons += gallons

print total_miles, total_gallons, total_miles/total_gallon
```